# How do I set up authenticated and unauthenticated routes in Angular with starting point /?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

In my Angular application, I would like to have a set of routes for the unauthenticated users and a set of routes for the authenticated. For example you should not be able to enter the login page at /login when authenticated.

That I can set up easily. The real trouble comes when I want the "starting point" for both scenarios to be /. What I mean is that when you enter the website for the first time (unauthenticated, of course) you should see the welcome page as http://example.com/. When you sign in and authenticate yourself you should also just see the url as http://example.com/.

At first I just had my `AppComponent` render a `PublicComponent` if unauthenticated and my route if authenticated. That worked until I had to implement more pages for the unauthenticated users and needed a router for that; the `PublicComponent` wasn't enough.

I've tried several things but none of them worked. Either the component couldn't be found in a navigate or it didn't show up.

Right now I have the routes

```
    {
        path: "",
        component: PublicComponent  // unauthenticated
    },
    {
        path: "pageA",
        component: PageAComponent   // unauthenticated
    }
    {
        path: "",
        component: HomeComponent,   // authenticated
        outlet: "authenticated"
    },
    {
        path: "pageB",
        component: PageBComponent,   // authenticated
        outlet: "authenticated"
    },
    {
        path: "pageC",
        component: PageCComponent,   // authenticated
        outlet: "authenticated"
    },
    {
        path: "**",
        component: PageNotFoundComponent
    }
```

`app.component.html`:

```
  <div *ngIf="isAuthenticated(); else notAuthenticated">
    <router-outlet name="authenticated"></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <ng-template #notAuthenticated>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </ng-template>
```

The unauthenticated routes (without the outlet) seems to work as they should. I can navigate between them. When entering a route that has the authenticated outlet it jumps to the wildcard, in this case the `PageNotFoundComponent`. That's fine.

When signing in and becoming an authenticated user, the `HomeComponent` greets me at / as it should, but it also seems to overtake the other routes. When entering /pageB, for example, the `HomeComponent` is being initialized and rendered again. So I tried giving it a full path match to stop it from overriding the other paths.

```
...
    {
        path: "",
        component: HomeComponent,
        outlet: "authenticated",
        pathMatch: "full"
    },
...
```

And now the other pages are just blank. No components are being rendered as if it cannot find them - but there are no errors either. I can enter any gibberish URL I want and just get a blank page.

I refuse to believe that it's impossible to do this. So, any help or advice is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

**Edit**

Yes, I've tried AuthGuard, but I have not yet been able to make it work with my setup.

Comment: Google **Angular** `authguard` :)

Comment: Thank you. I've tried AuthGuard but without any luck. Please see my comment on Chukwudis answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should use AuthGuard to implement that then specify in your route which link is applicable to the authGuard like this.

```
{
    path: "pageC",
    component: PageCComponent, : canActivate: [AuthGuard]
},
```

Then you can use the angular CLI to generate an AuthGuard which is something like this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from 
'@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';



@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

canActivate(
     next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
     state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
       if (this.auth.authenticated) { // This is the injected auth service which depends on what you are using
            return true; 
           }

       console.log('access denied!')
       this.router.navigate(['/login']);
       return false


   }
```

}

You can also use the link below for more information
https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

Comment: Note: Your router outlet on the view should be kept default and no if authenticated, the authguard ensures all that

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It doesn't seem to work the way that I want though. Using the AuthGuard on HomeComponent, the PublicComponent keeps showing even when the user is authenticated. Switching positions so that the HomeComponent is before the PublicComponent in the router array, it loops endlessly and crashes.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response, you can check this link i found for you on medium. it should guide you through that. https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3

Answer (score 0):

The order of the routes in the configuration matters and this is by design. The router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching routes, so more specific routes should be placed above less specific routes.

Also, should use route guards for route security, refer: https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate